# What is conda shell activation?

Tags: anaconda

Anaconda [Installing in silent mode](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/silent-mode/#linux-macos) says

> The installer will not prompt you for anything, including setup of your shell to activate conda. To add this activation in your current shell session:

```
eval "$(command conda 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
```

What does this line actually do and what files (eg. update bashrc or bash_profile, etc) are affected?

After having done this, what will happen when I open a bash shell or start a new login?

If there is a detailed documentation, please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;** Conda shell activation is the process of defining some shell functions that facilitate activating and deactivating Conda environments, as well as some optional features such as updating PS1 to show the active environment.

---

In Conda v4.4, there was a major overhaul with how Conda manages environment isolation. Part of this was to manage activation of environments with a shell function `conda()` that takes arguments like `activate` or `install`, rather than having an `activate` script which users previously had to `source activate`.

The particular command in OP generates the bash code to define the `conda()` function, some auxiliary functions it needs, and environment variables, then evaluates this code in your current shell. The reason why this isn't a fixed script is that what Conda does here is generated on the fly using the `conda` entry point (i.e., Python code), and takes into account the configuration settings found in `~/.condarc`.

You can completely inspect this code without evaluating it by just running

```
conda shell.bash hook
```

which will output the code as a string. The common elements everyone will see are the `conda()` function and its auxiliaries (e.g., starting with `__conda_`). Other aspects are configuration-dependent. For instance, if `auto_activate_base` is true (the default), then a `conda activate base` will be emitted at the end.

Comment: concerning the question  `what files (eg. update .bashrc or .bash_profile, etc) are affected` one may add that no files are changed and nothing will have changed when you open a new terminal or run a new login. To have the changes permanent one would need to run `conda init bash`  which would modify the init file such that the hooks are established once a new shell is opened.